# ProgressBar without AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I'd like to show the progress bar, generate the computation, then after I do that I'd like the progressbar to disappear and I want to set the textview to the result of my generate result. Yet when I do the below, the progress bar never displays, yet the textview updates appropriately. I originally wanted to do this using AsyncTask but since thats been deprecated I wanted to try a modern method but I'm afraid I can't get it to work. Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
genResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                // do onPreExecute stuff
                                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                        // do your stuff
                        boolean res = exp.genResult();
                        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                        while(System.nanoTime()-startTime<50000){
                        }
                        result.outcomes.add(res);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                // do onPostExecute stuff
                                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                lastRes.setText(Boolean.toString(res));


                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

Below is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gen_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="generate result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.941" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_bin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gen_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.153" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/detail_bin_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View Details"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.941"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backbutton_bin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="go back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/detail_bin_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.105"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastresultbin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:text="lastresult"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/backbutton_bin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/probabilityViewer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
        android:text="Probability"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.65"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lastresultbin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail_bin_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plaintext_lastres_bin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Last Result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lastresultbin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.105"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/backbutton_bin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plaintext_prob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:text="Probability of Success"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail_bin_button" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you share how your progress bar is set up? It may be hidden underneath another component

Comment: @user3170251 Sure I can, what information would you like? The XML file or the rest of file that genResult is in?

Comment: Lets see the XML file where the progress bar is

Comment: @user3170251 Its at the bottom of the XML file. Please excuse the appearance if you view the design, it is still a prototype!

Comment: From what i see it looks fine. I'm starting to think that using `nanoTime()` is the culprit, the time difference may be too quick to see a difference. Try replacing `System.nanoTime()` with `System.currentTimeInMillis()` and replacing `50000` with `5000`

Comment: @user3170251 Thank you so much! That worked perfectly

Comment: glad to help. Please do accept my answer when you get the chance!

Comment: Note that you can use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead of a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `System.nanoTime()` used in the `while` loop was too quick to complete. When we switch to using `System.currentTimeInMillis()` we can notice a difference in the delay and thus the spinner shows and hides as expected.